# Overflowed content appears to still be calculated in page width

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Most of the pages of my React app are set up the same way -- there is a PageContainer component (div) that has some padding around the left and right edges, and either one or two columns of content. When you decrease the width of the window, the right containers move with the edge of the window (I am using `justify-content: space-between`) until either the right column flows beneath the left column, or the minimum width is reached and the content overflows the viewport.

However, on one page I have a div that is meant to show a scrollable calendar view. It shows 4 days at a time, and you scroll to the right to see the rest of the days. This div is set to `overflow: auto`. The problem is that the page width appears to be calculated including the overflowed content, pushing the nav elements that should be flush with the right-hand edge of the browser window out of the viewport entirely.

Is there a way to ensure that only the div that encloses this content is factored into the page width?

EDIT:
While I am aware that I can set a max-width on the container that contains the overflowing content, this is a hackier approach than I'd like to take. The ideal scenario is this box grows and expands with the page, but always has the 55px of padding on the right side (never overflows the viewport).

Comment: You may get more help if you are able to set up a demo of the problem, using something like Codepen.

Comment: i second providing a code example.

just spent some time trying to answer but came to the realization i dont really understand what your problem is.

Can you just give the columns an overflow:auto so that when the width of the calendar scroller (housed inside the column container) expands greater than the width of the column container it adds a scrollbar instead of stretching the column width out? that way column width can still be totally dynamic but when the calendar scroller width becomes wider, instead of stretching the parent it creates its own scrollbar